# How can I use GitKraken on a private network?

Tags: gitkraken

I've been using GitKraken on Windows for various projects and now I have to do some development on a private network (no internet access). But when I start the application it asks me to create an account. I can't do that on this network.

How can I configure GitKraken on this network without creating an account?

Comment: https://twitter.com/gitkraken/status/691648833894387712 - Initial usage requires you to be online to register the product, Axosoft themselves even say so.

Comment: Yeah, I read that too. I was hoping for some solution otherwise I'll have to use some other product, but gitkraken really does the job well.

Comment: Don't think there is a solution that will work if you're not connected to the public internet. It's not a product that was designed to run on private/internal networks or offline. You can try reaching out to Axosoft but they will probably give you the exact same information.

Comment: This is, however, a very common scenario for sensitive projects, although obviously not their target audience.

Comment: Only me finds out pretty lame to create an account just to use a local repo or even if you want to use a repo in the cloud to create an account only to integrate it to your existing account? There's not a single good excuse for asking to create an account for a tool will run local

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to take (for Windows):
`...\user\AppData\Roaming\.gitkraken` 
and 
`...\user\AppData\Roaming\GitKraken`
from machine with internet access and place it to machine with a private network.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for Linux?

Comment: I'm on linux but this is still the general solution. I think I will write the equivalent answer for linux users..

Comment: OK added an answer based on this one but for linux users

Answer (score 6):

Just go to YOUR_USER_FOLDER\AppData\Roaming\ .gitkraken folder and open config file. Edit date to many years later. If it did not work, remove .gitkraken folder, run the app, login with fake email and password, and edit config file again.
Have fun.

Comment: Edit what date?  Do you mean make a fake account from a computer with internet access?

Comment: No. Just enter an optional username and password.

Comment: There is only one "date" key under "registration" key.

Comment: There is nothing to edit unless you've connected from a computer _with internet access_ (as mentioned by the [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41542549/1037948))

Comment: My pc at work does not have access to internet and I did the work successfully. Maybe because I have local network access.

Comment: I can confirm this works! GK downloads and installs as expected but asks for an account every time it opens. Just close the logon window and in the top bar click [Not now]. Enjoy using it until the date you put (many years in the future)

Comment: The "not now" appears to have gone, and it's not obvious which config files this answer is referring to. (there's a whole folder full of various files, none of which appear to have an account details placeholder)

Answer (score 0):

To use Gitkraken without network access **on Linux** you will need to copy files from an existing account that has been setup and connected whilst connected to the internet.

**existingUser** : the user that has already been setup whilst connected to internet

**newUser** : the user that will need access without internet access (eg. root user)

Open shell and run the following, replacing existingUser and newUser with the appropriate users:

```
#First I backup the GitKraken settings as these weren't working:

su newUser
cd ~
mv .gitkraken .gitkraken.dud

#Now I copy the working GitKraken settings from the existingUser
cp -r ~existingUser/.gitkraken  .

# Now run gitkraken
gitkraken
```